# how to create a program that will read an encrypted text from a file and will create a new file with the decrypted one

Tags: python, function, encryption, file-io

i would like to know how to create 2 things please:

• To write a program that will read an encrypted text from a file and will create a new file with the decrypted one.

• To create a dictionary base of the decryption page

my decryption page looks like this and it has to be a LIST '' a=z, b=y, c=x, d=w...''

this translation working good, but i need to read the encrypted string from an existing file, translate it and to write the decrypted string in a new file

[Example code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4R3OY.png)

Comment: Please do not show code as an `img` file, instead code it out in the question with correct format

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

```
# ------- DEFs------------

def encrypt(text):
  encrypted_text = ""
  alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
  for char in text:
    if char in alphabet:
      encrypted_text+= alphabet[25-alphabet.find(char)]
    else:
      encrypted_text+= char
  return encrypted_text




# ------- MAIN ------------
# alphabet
inttab = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

# inverted alphabet
outtab = 'zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba'

print(inttab.find('a'))
# > 0

print(outtab.find('a'))
# > 25

# cipher -> inttab = outtab - 25
text = 'hello world!'
encrypted_text = encrypt(text)

print(encrypted_text)
# > svool dliow!

decrypted_text = encrypt(encrypted_text)

print(decrypted_text)
# > hello world!
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a Dictionary to find for each encrypted char entry its corresponding translation.

```py
## Create an empty dictionary
your_dictionary = {}

## Fill your_dictionary with the (key, values) couples
## With keys your key list, and values your values list
for key, value in zip(keys, values):
    your_dictionary[key] = value

## Decrypt your encrypted message
## With enc_message the encrypted message
decrypted_message = ""
for c in enc_message:
    decrypted_message = decrypted_message+your_dictionary[c]
```

Now you may want to play it a little bit more secure, because you may face some issues if you try to decrypt either a char you havent added as a key in the dictionary, or a space.

```py
decrypted_message = ""
for c in enc_message:
    if c.isspace():
        decrypted_message = decrypted_message + c
    elif c not in your_dictionary :
        ## Handle this case how you want. By default you can add it.
        decrypted_message = decrypted_message + c
    else :
        decrypted_message=decrypted_message + your_dictionary[c]
```

So, as you requested the encrypted and decrypted message should come from a file and should be outputted as a file, you can use the following functions and instruction to perform the whole cycle :

```py
## Decrypt a message with a specific dictionary
def decrypt_message(message, your_dict):
    decrypted_message = ""
    word = ""
    for index, c in enumerate(enc_message):
        print(c)
        if c.isspace():
            decrypted_message = decrypted_message + c
        elif c not in your_dict :
            decrypted_message = decrypted_message + c
        else :
            decrypted_message = decrypted_message + your_dict[c]
    return decrypted_message

## Populate a dictionary with the given couples
def populate_dictionary(keys, values):
    your_dictionary = {}
    for key, value in zip(keys, values):
        your_dictionary[key] = value
    return your_dictionary

## Example keys
keys = ['a', 'b', 'c']
## Example values
values = ['d', 'e', 'f']

## Open the input file
with open('encryptedMessage.txt', 'r') as file:
    enc_message = file.read().replace('\n', '')

## Populating the dictionary
dic = populate_dictionary(keys, values)
## Decrypting the message
dec_message = decrypt_message(enc_message, dic)

## Creating and saving the decrypted message in the output file.
text_file = open("decryptedMessage.txt", "w")
text_file.write(dec_message)
text_file.close()
```